# ILGenerator emiting call GetHashCode on int

Tags: c#, .net-core

When I run this code:

```
var il = getHashCode.GetILGenerator();
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S, 17); // put "17" on the stack
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Int32).GetMethod("GetHashCode", new Type[] { })); 
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

I'm getting System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

When I box the value:

```
var il = getHashCode.GetILGenerator();
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S, 17); // put "17" on the stack
il.Emit(OpCodes.Box, typeof(Int32));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Int32).GetMethod("GetHashCode", new Type[] { })); 
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

The return value is -1875039000, but should be 17.

How can I emit the correct call?

Comment: Write the code in C# first, then use a decompiler like ildasm.exe to look at the opcodes it used.  It doesn't work the way you think, the simple value types are heavily optimized to avoid boxing.

Comment: You need to store in a local and then reload from that local. Some form of stloc/ldloc. Try checking sharplab

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 the local is needed so that the address to that local is pushed as a pointer onto the stack (`ldloca.s`), not the value itself.

Answer (score 2):

`GetHashCode()` is an instance method, hence you need to call it on a "reference". While you don't need to box an integer, the `this` parameter you need to push onto the stack is not the integer value itself but a pointer to the integer value.

For this reason, you need a local variable in which you can store the integer value, then push a pointer to that local value onto the stack (`ldloca.s`) and call the instance method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var method = new DynamicMethod("Get17HashCode", typeof(int), new Type[0], typeof(Program).Module);
    var ilGenerator = method.GetILGenerator();
    ilGenerator.DeclareLocal(typeof(int));
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S, 17);
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca_S, 0);
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(int).GetMethod(nameof(int.GetHashCode)));
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    var delegateFunction = (Func<int>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int>));

    var result = delegateFunction();
    Console.WriteLine($"Got {result}");
}
```

The reason you got a `NullReferenceException` is probably because the address `17` is still in the virtual memory page registered at address `0` that the CLR registered a handler for null references for. Large values should lead to `AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory` (assuming a short form representation on the stack).

Comment: Why does calling the method on a boxed instance not work?

Comment: Then you would need to do a virtual method call on `object`'s `GetHashCode`: `ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(object).GetMethod(nameof(object.GetHashCode)));`